# Is an ADS-B IN able to receive signal from ADS-B OUT of the same aircraft?

Tags: ads-b

Suppose I have an ADS-B IN on my aircraft and I am interested in receiving also data sent from ADS-B OUT of my own aircraft. Is it technically possible or are there any issues due to the relative position between transmitter and receiver or anything else?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? There some cases where it is technically not possible, but in general there are no fundamental technical limitations of receiving your own ADS-B signals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On small aircraft many operators use portable ADS-B IN receivers which typically do not have the ability to sense suppression signals from their own transponder/UAT transmissions and so they will pick up their own signal.

Most installed systems have that suppression functionality so this won't happen.

The suppression is simply a wire between the two units that if the transmitter is transmitting, it goes high, which tells the receiver to ignore whatever it is receiving at the moment.

So if you want to "receive" yourself, simply snip the suppression wire if you have one...

Comment: One of the reasons to have a suppression function is to protect the sensitive receiver front end from being blown out by a high power transmission a couple of feet away, or sometimes even on a shared RX/TX antenna. If you are looking for an effective way of making your receiver as deaf as your 95 year old granny, cut the suppression wire.